# Google Spreadsheets API how to insert a new column with data

Tags: curl, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert a new COLUMN with an array of new data after "Age" column.

[image]

From [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) and [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) I got to this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{my_ID}/values/Sheet1!A1:C2:append?insertDataOption=OVERWRITE&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {my_AUTH_TOKEN}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
    "values": [
        ["Last Name", "Unknown"]
    ]
}'
```

However, it keeps doing this:

[image]

What I want to do is to insert the `["Last Name", "Unknown"]` in the `D` column instead of the `A3`. Any hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put the values of `"Last Name"` and `"Unknown"` to the rows of column "D" using Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using curl.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- When you want to put the values of `"Last Name"` and `"Unknown"` to the rows of the column "D", please use `[["Last Name"],["UnKnown"]]` instead of `[["Last Name", "Unknown"]]`.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the method of spreadsheets.values.append is used.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{my_ID}/values/Sheet1!D1:append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer {my_AUTH_TOKEN}' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"values":[["Last Name"],["UnKnown"]]}'
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the method of spreadsheets.values.update is used.

```
curl --request PUT \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{my_ID}/values/Sheet1!D1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer {my_AUTH_TOKEN}' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"values":[["Last Name"],["UnKnown"]]}'
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Your solution works fine, however if I put `values:[["Last Name"],["UnKnown"]]` it yells me a 401 error. So I needed to set it as it was before: `values:["Last Name","UnKnown"]`.

Comment: @assembler Thank you for replying and adding the information.